# Calculation of system response time

Tags: performance, performance-testing

I've developed software and now I'm going to monitor the performance of system, the system is almost working well, except in some periods of working faces some slowness. Now I have prepared o log related to system response and the time which the response has been generated, the log time is like below:
Process#1   step1:   300 millisecond    step2: 700 milliseconds     step 3: 10 millisecond
Process#2   step1: 10 millisecond       step2: 50 milliseconds      step 3: 4 milliseconds
Process#3   step1:2 millisecond     step2: 40 milliseconds      step 3: 80 milliseconds

Now I want to detect that which process has suspicious response time, what is the rule for this in concepts of software engineering? I mean I have tried the values which are greater than average + 3* standard deviation, but it did not work, only a few data has been marked but I know that data more than 100 millisecond is not normal
What is the rule for this purpose in software engineering, how we detect the bottle neck of system?

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code/the app?

Answer (score 2):

There's no real rule of thumb for finding bottlenecks.  The rule is, you measure objectively which parts of your application are slow, and then you have a definitive answer.

Much engineering time is wasted by trying to optimise code that turns out not to be slow in the first place.  So measure, and then act.  Make sure you can reproduce the slow performance, so that you can repeat a test and test your changes reliably.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this Wiki page, there are many links for software that watches the performance of an application.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_profiler

Comment: I'm not looking for profiling tools I'm just looking for an software related rule to detect the errors in response time manually like the 80/20 rule.

Comment: You mean like "80% of your performance issues are caused by the 20% of your code that is slow?"

Comment: It looks like you already know what parts of your code take the longest from the log file. Why not edit how that code is written to make the entire process run faster?